# How to stop an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' when creating textboxes at run time in VB

Tags: vb.net, textbox

For a project I require the creation of textboxes at run time, to this end I have used this code;

```
Dim AOP As Integer = GlobalVariables.AOP
Dim tb(11, 11) As TextBox
Dim LocationX As Integer
Dim LocationY As Integer
Dim count As Integer = 2

LocationX = 10
LocationY = 10
tb(1, 0).Name = "txtRoot"
tb(1, 0).Size = New Size(170, 20)
tb(1, 0).Location = New Point(LocationX, LocationY)
tb(1, 0).Visible = False
```

I am then able to loop it using this For loop;

```
For i = 1 To AOP
        If count > AOP Then

        Else
            If i = AOP Then
                LocationY = LocationY + 10
                LocationX = 10
                tb(count, 0).Name = "txtXValue" & 0 & "YValue" & count
                tb(count, 0).Size = New Size(170, 20)
                tb(count, 0).Location = New Point(LocationX, LocationY)
                Controls.Add(tb(count, 0))
                count = count + 1
                i = 1
            Else
                LocationX = LocationX + 10
                tb(count, i).Name = "txtXValue" & i & "YValue" & count
                tb(count, i).Size = New Size(170, 20)
                tb(count, i).Location = New Point(LocationX, LocationY)
                Controls.Add(tb(count, i))
            End If
        End If
Next
```

This works in theory, however, when the code reaches the line;

```
tb(1, 0).Name = "txtRoot"
```

It returns the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
I am wondering if there is anyway around this? or if this way of creating textboxes isn't possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You do not create any textboxes in this code. You do create `Point`s and `Size`s though.

Comment: What is the value of GlobalVariables.AOP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The value of GlobalVariables.AOP is set by a textbox on another form, it can be anything from 1 to 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have initialized the array but not added initialized `TextBoxes`, the array contains currently only `Nothing`. Also note that arrays are zero based, so the first `TextBox` is in `tb(0, 0)`.

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To tb.GetLength(0) - 1
    For ii As Int32 = 0 To tb.GetLength(1) - 1
        tb(i, ii) = New TextBox()
        tb(i, ii).Visible = False
        ' .... '
    Next
Next
```

Now all are initialized.